# Generated URL by Html.RouteLink with special characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I have the following line

```
           @Html.RouteLink(type.Description, "ListingsWithTypeSpecified", new { country = Model.CountryCode, state = Model.State, city = Model.CurrentCity.Name.ToLower(), description = type.Description.ToLower(), id = type.TypeID })
```

which produces

```
http://some.com:9609/ca/on/london/physiotherapy%20%20%26%20acupuncture/2
```

and
    http://some.com:9609/ca/on/london/health%20department/19

first one has spaces and a &, second one just has a space
for the first one, I would like to still show

```
 http://localhost:9609/ca/on/london/physiotherapy and acupuncture/2
```

for this one I understand replacing the & with "and" will work, however I still do not want %20 as spaces instead I would like to have a clean url.
Which method should I be using to properly have friendly url shown by what Html.RouteLink creates?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the space with a -
e.g.

```
type.Description.ToLower().Replace(" ", "-")
```

Comment: can this be done by calling some built in function, I was trying to avoid having to manually replace characters, but instead use a built in that will handle it approperiately

Comment: You could add your own extension method, something like this:
`public static string ReplaceSpace(string description)
        {
            return description.Replace(" ", "-");
        }`
Then add your replace rules as needed